# Is there anyway to re-render navation bar without calling setParams (react-navigation)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm implementing multi-language feature for my app, but i got stuck at changing react navigation header title (using react-navigation). I don't want to call setParams in every screen to change header title based on selected language.

This is my stack:

```
Home -> Settings -> App Settings -> Language Settings.
```

I select language at `Language Setting` screen. After go back by press default back button on navigation bar, `static navigationOptions` in `App Settings` screen is called (this is where I set title based on current language) even though I don't call setParams(), I don't know why it's not re-rendered => header title doesn't change.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

---

Hi @JavaEvgan
This is my code:

```
    <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
      state: this.props.navigationState
    })}/>
```

connect to redux store

```
export default connect(state => ({
  navigationState: state.navigationState,
}), dispatch => ({
  dispatch: dispatch
}))(MainLayoutContainer)
```

Comment: Aren't you using Redux with react? You can create initialState in reducer and change it depending on language option chosen.

Comment: Yes, I'm using react-redux. I can change screen's content based on language, but react navigation doesn't change. React-navigation header doesn't re-render even if redux store change

Comment: Can you please provide a code of your navigation component I believe that you might be using constructor with props there instead of the props from Redux.

Comment: I just added code in question. I can dispatch action to `navigationState` reducer to perform `push` and `pop` for navigation.

Comment: And what about your AppNavigator component, how does it look like?

Comment: sorry for not making it clear, I use react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/

Comment: what about using "i18n" or something similar for multilanguage? im very satisfied with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out solution, use screenProps to pass down extra information to children
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props

```
    <AppNavigator
      screenProps={this.props.settings}
      navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
      state: this.props.navigationState
    })}/>
```

and connect it to redux store

```
export default connect(state => ({
  settings: state.settings,
  navigationState: state.navigationState,
}), dispatch => ({
  dispatch: dispatch
}))(MainLayoutContainer)
```

Like this, `static navigationOptions` get called and re-render everytime settings on store changed

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution for you from the original documentation and it's very easy. You simply have to create two(or more) navigation components for different language versions and one parent component. In parent component you will need to use a "Conditional rendering" (if statement) and return the right navigation depending on your state. Check out the original documentation for conditional rendering:

[ReactJS docs - Conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

From docs:

> Consider these two components:

```
function UserGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}

function GuestGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Please sign up.</h1>;
}
```

> We'll create a Greeting component that displays either of these components depending on whether a user is logged in:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
if (isLoggedIn) {
  return <UserGreeting />;
}
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // Try changing to isLoggedIn={true}:
  <Greeting isLoggedIn={false} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> [Try it on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZpVxNq?editors=0011)
>
> This example renders a different greeting depending on the value of `isLoggedIn` in prop

Comment: So I have create 10 navigator if I need to support 10 languages ? I don't think it's a good ideal

Comment: I think you have to do so. Or you have to add if statement inside your AppNavigator component that will check the state for current language version and paste the right text which is the same, but more "uncomfortable".

Comment: And can you please provide your AppNavigator component's code. I would also suggest you to pass your state to it with a prop like that <AppNavigator navstate={this.props.navigationState}/> and then use it inside AppNavigator controller just like a normal props this.props.navstate

Comment: You can also pass your values that need to be translated to the Nav component using props. And inside your Nav just use them to display text. So you will pass different values based on language setting and you will not need to create multiple nav components.

Comment: Seems convoluted. Why not do `function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
if (isLoggedIn) {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}
  return <h1>Please sign in.</h1>;
}`. Reduces the number of lines of code by a lot.